# How to bind a function in the constructor so that it can take on the parameter

Tags: reactjs

In my React component I have the following function:

```
removeOption(idx) {
    var opts = this.state.opts;
    opts.splice(idx,1);
    this.state({opts: opts});

}
```

In order for it to be bound to the component I need to bind it in the constructor. Usually I use

> this.functionName = this.functionName(this);

but previously I only dealt with functions that do not have parameters.

> this.removeOption = this.removeOption.bind(this);

does not work - I get an error `this.state is not a function`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats because `this.state` isn't a function. You are looking for `this.setState({opts: opts})` You would use the same binding method even if the function takes arguments. the `.bind(this)` just ensures that when that method is called `this` is scoped to that component instance.

Comment: OMG, can't believe I did not catch that! Thanks!